# Hibernate collection retains reference to deleted entity

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, spring-data-jpa

We use spring-data hibernate as ORM for our db access. I have entities set up as follows:

```
class E1 {
    @Column(name = "e1_id")
    private BigDecimal e1_id;   

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "e1", orphanRemoval=true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private Collection<E2> e2List;
}

class E2 {
    @Column(name = "e2_id")
    private BigDecimal e2_id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "e1_id", referencedColumnName = "e1_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private E1 e1;
}
```

Now I try the following:
create a new E1 and save using spring JPA repository, without an explicit spring transaction.

```
E1 detachedE1 = e1Repo.save(e1);
```

e1 has a non-empty collection of e2.

I delete the e2 entities from e1 and then save e1 in a spring transaction.

then, I try to use the detachedE1 as follows:

```
   detachedE1.setE2Collection(Collections.emptyList())
   e1Repo.save(detachedE1)
```

The above code errors out, and the error basically says:

springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find entity.E2 with id 1.00

My question is, how is JPA retaining a reference to a deleted collection. I set the E2 collection to empty list. And I also verified that the entity returned by e1Repo.find(detachedE1.e1_id) has an empty collection.

thanks in advance for any replies/pointers!

Just wanted to add we use hibernate hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured this out after digging around the hibernate code using the debugger. The detached entities' collection is really a PersistentBag, which shouldn't be too surprising. 
But the persistent bag maintains a snapShot, which is not cleared when I set the collection to an emptyList.

Just for the sake of testing out my final theory, I added the following:

```
((PersistentCollection)e1.getE2Collection()).setSnapshot(null, null, null);
```

After this, the hibernate persistent context was able to successfully merge the detached entity, with the E2 collection set to an empty list.